# CodeDom code generation, TypeAttribute ExplicitLayout doesn't generate a custom attribute?

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

I'm using CodeDom to generate a structure, I'm trying to indicate the explicit layout of the fields via a custom attribute.
I've managed to do it using a normal `CodeAttributeDeclaration` instance, but then I noticed that the enumeration System.Reflection.TypeAttributes contains a field named ExplicitLayout which should be what I'm looking for. I've used it this way:

```
CodeTypeDeclaration type = new CodeTypeDeclaration();
type.Name = "MyStructure";
type.IsStruct = true;
type.TypeAttributes = TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.ExplicitLayout;
```

However this doesn't generate the `StructLayout` attribute I need, why?

Comment: Because that's not what determines whether a type actually has the attribute.  A *struct* type for example will have Type.IsExplicitLayout return true, without it actually having the attribute.  It is there only for Reflection purposes, not for generating code.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, so the TypeAttributes enumeration isn't meant for what I was looking for, got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.TypesAttributes.ExplicitLayout` doesn't automatically generate the `StructLayoutAttribute`, so I had to declare it "manually":

```
type.CustomAttributes.Add(new CodeAttributeDeclaration("StructLayout",
    new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(LayoutKind)), "Explicit"))));
```